# php using a variable outside a nested for loop

Tags: php, mysql

Hi this may be a newbe question but i cant get my code to work.
I´m trying to sum the numbers given in cells in a database. And then make them easily accessible by making an array of the summed values.

To make things a little bit clearer. The database contain many rows that will go thru the same sort of code. Every row have atleast 40 cells (i´m only picking out cell 13-33).
The cells contains 12 numbers each "011011100005". I dont want to sum all cells together.
Just sum the nubers in every cell.

```
<?php 

// Get row 1 from the database and put into variable $row1          
$row1 = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// create an emty variable with the name $str, for use later outside of the for loop         
$str = '';

// read in the cells with index 13 to 33.
for ($i = 13; $i < 33; ++$i) {
    // put the values in a string and add "," between the values.
    $str .= "$row1[$i],";                   
};

// Split the values into an array, useing "," as an divider.
$arr2 = ( explode( ',', $str ));

// Read in all the values from $arr2, index 0 to 20.
for ($p = 0; $p < 20; ++$p) {

    // make variable $b2 to the values that are in $arr2[index 0 to 20].
    $b2 = $arr2[$p];

    $a2 = 0;  // $a2 to 0

    // for the first 10 numbers in the given strings $arr2[index 0 till 20].
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
        // sum those 10 numbers in every string
        $a2 += $b2[$i];
    };

    // this is giving me the correct numbers like "909090900000000010230" 
    // 21 numbers that is the sum of every strings value.
    print_r($a2); 
};
```

Here starts my problem, using $a2 outside the loop will not work. How do i fix this?

```
$arr1 = str_split($a2);
// Make an array of the string $a2, spliting every number. (not working)

echo $arr1[5];    // echo one number by the index. (not working)
?>
```

So my problem is that a need to be able to echo the $arr1 in many places further down the code.

Comment: 1. **mysql_*** is **DEPRECATED**, 2. Why you dont calculate that directly on SQL Statement/Query?

Comment: 3. Try to debug the right way. **error_reporting(E_ALL);** + **ini_set('display_errors', true);** and **var_dump()** / **print_r()** is your friend

Comment: sry i am very new to all of this coding ... 3 weeks into it now. Every suggestion is appreciated

Comment: i have been using  
       $Sc2 = $row1[14];
   $a2 = 0;
   for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $a2 += $Sc2[$i];
   }
But using that i will fill 1000 rows of code easily

Comment: Why not have `$a2` in the same scope as `$arr1 = str_split($a2);`?

Comment: Why not sum up the values in the database query?

Comment: if i put the $a2 outside of the loop it will give me the wrong value

Comment: Mike Brant pls give an exampel how that would look like

Comment: @user3341623 - what do you mean by "it will give me the wrong value"? Where? I think we need to know more of your code and especially your scopes.

Comment: i have edited the question hope it will make things a little bit more clear. The code is more or less exactly as in my real enviroment.

Comment: @user3341623 `SELECT SUM(column) AS total FROM table`.

Comment: h2ooooooo cant get that one to work. Giving me answer: Resource id#9.

Comment: Please provide the full code or else we cannot help - there must be a scoping issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if you want a variable to be visible outside the loop you have to create it outside the loop. So initialise it before starting the for loop.

Also arrays are easier to manipulate than a string with multiple values in it. So I made a few changes to make things easier for processing.

```
<?php 

// Get row 1 from the database and put into variable $row1          
$row1 = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// read in the cells with index 13 to 33.
$cells = array();
for ($i = 13; $i < 33; ++$i) {
    // put the values in an array
    $cells[] = $row1[$i];                   
};

// init cell total array
$cell_tot = array(); 
// Read in all the values from $arr2, index 0 to 20.
for ($p = 0; $p < 20; ++$p) {

    // make variable $b2 to the values that are in $arr2[index 0 to 20].
    $cell = $cells[$p];

    // for the first 10 numbers in the given strings $arr2[index 0 till 20].
    $cell_tot[$p] = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
        // sum those 10 numbers in every string
        $cell_tot[$p] += $cell[$i];
    };

    // this is giving me the correct numbers like "909090900000000010230" 
    // 21 numbers that is the sum of every strings value.
    echo $cell_tot[$p]; 
}; 
// cell_tot now visible outside the loop and is an array
// one occurance for each sumation process
// and contains one occurance for each sumation
// and not another string which is difficult to do anythig with
// also resolves the problem of one sumation adding up to more than a single char i.e. 1 to 9
// 10 would have caused you a problem
print_r($cell_tot);
```

Comment: That's not correct - variables are visible inside a loop if they are in the same function. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for variables scoping

Comment: Ty so much! this is great working perfect :D Hope to return the favor some time (when i learned some things myself)

Comment: Hi again @RiggsFolly i was wondering if it is possible to also get the NULL value passed thru the script. Right now the "Null" is converted into "0" and i dont want a "0" if there has not been written anything to the database field.

Comment: Not sure where you mean. Maybe it would be better to ask another question.